# Multiple Closing Criteria

Tags: discussion

Occasionally I run into questions that have a few criteria for closing (e.g. an overly broad, opinionated, question about a JS framework that's hardly related to Drupal). Should I worry about which flag to choose? Do any of them have priority? Is closing based on the number of votes in particular category, or just the absolute number of flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just choose the closing reason you think applies better to the question. It is important to choose a reason that really applies to the question, in order to give the correct message to the user who asked the question.

Closing reasons have all the same priority, and don't change the number of votes necessary to close the question. Just in case of voting to close as duplicate, the votes could be less than 5, if the OP agrees that the other question helped them; it also happens when a diamond moderator cast a closing vote.

What really changes is the reason shown when the question is closed: The one with more votes (or the one chosen by a diamond moderator) is shown as selected one. In the case two closing reasons has the same number of votes, the last selected (or the first selected?) is shown.

Comment: Thanks. I'll think of it as the best signal to user about what's wrong with question.

Comment: What I usually do is checking which closing reason applies in the same order they are listed (top to bottom), to avoid (for example) to close as too broad a question that really is off-topic. If a user is asking about an error message given from a PHP function, all the details added to the question would not make it acceptable, as _too broad_ could make them understand.